# How can I use sed or tr to delete strings like "[digits]"?

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl, tr

I recently had to handle lots of downloaded paper, which included many annoying "`[...]`" in the text. Like this:

> Local delivery of a wide selection of growth factors [e.g. platelet-derived growth factor and BMP 2] from electrospun membranes/scaffolds has demonstrated to enhance cell activity in vitro [41] as well as bone regeneration in vivo [47] . Due to space limitations, the authors recommend that readers refer to the outstanding reviews recently published on this topic for further details [34–36].

Desired output:

> Local delivery of a wide selection of growth factors [e.g. platelet-derived growth factor and BMP 2] from electrospun membranes/scaffolds has demonstrated to enhance cell activity in vitro as well as bone regeneration in vivo. Due to space limitations, the authors recommend that readers refer to the outstanding reviews recently published on this topic for further details.

how can I use `tr` or `sed` to delete this "`[digits]`"? I have tried

```
tr -d '[\*]' 

sed 's/[[*]]//g'
```

but neither of them worked.

Where should I do the escape and how could I get them deleted without delete other characters that were in the brackets (like the [e.g. platelet-derived growth factor and BMP 2] )?

Comment: What about `[36-42]`? This is not only composed of [digits], but it would seem as if you wanted to delete them. That's why this kind of question is always best accompained by expected output.

Comment: yes, I want to delete [ digit - digit ] too, sorry for not mentioning that in the question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output you want to see from that example. If this is for an academic paper, remember that you can also see things like `[24, 56, 34-36]`, so if you need to deal with those too, make sure to include them. Also tell us if there can be other things within square brackets that you do _not_ want to remove (e.g. `[ . . . ]`) or things that are in square brackets but not numbers (e.g. `[personal communication]`) etc.

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/\h*\[\d+(\p{dash}\d+)?\]//g' < your-file
```

Where `\p{dash}` matches characters in the *dash punctuation* category (such as -֊־᐀᠆‐‑‒–—―⁓⁻₋−⸗⸚⸺⸻⹀〜〰゠︱︲﹘﹣－).

That deletes the `h`orizontal whitespace *before* but not *after* those `[x]`. That means however that on your sample, `in vivo [47] . Due` becomes `in vivo . Due`. You could improve it by also removing horizontal whitespace *after* the `[x]` if it's ultimately followed by `!;:,.?` or the end of the line with:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/\h*\[\d+(\p{dash}\d+)?\](\h*(?=[!;:,.?]|$))?//g'
```

With `-Mopen=locale`, characters are decoded/encoded as per the locale's charmap. Categories (dash, digit, blank above) are determined based on Unicode data. The list of characters that each match will depend on the version of perl (which determines the version of Unicode being used). For instance, here and in a locale using UTF-8 encoding, `\d` matches on `0123456789٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉०१२३४५६७८९০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮੯૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯୦୧୨୩୪୫୬୭୮୯௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮௯౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౯೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯෦෧෨෩෪෫෬෭෮෯๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘๙໐໑໒໓໔໕໖໗໘໙༠༡༢༣༤༥༦༧༨༩၀၁၂၃၄၅၆၇၈၉႐႑႒႓႔႕႖႗႘႙០១២៣៤៥៦៧៨៩᠐᠑᠒᠓᠔᠕᠖᠗᠘᠙᥆᥇᥈᥉᥊᥋᥌᥍᥎᥏᧐᧑᧒᧓᧔᧕᧖᧗᧘᧙᪀᪁᪂᪃᪄᪅᪆᪇᪈᪉᪐᪑᪒᪓᪔᪕᪖᪗᪘᪙᭐᭑᭒᭓᭔᭕᭖᭗᭘᭙᮰᮱᮲᮳᮴᮵᮶᮷᮸᮹᱀᱁᱂᱃᱄᱅᱆᱇᱈᱉᱐᱑᱒᱓᱔᱕᱖᱗᱘᱙꘠꘡꘢꘣꘤꘥꘦꘧꘨꘩꣐꣑꣒꣓꣔꣕꣖꣗꣘꣙꤀꤁꤂꤃꤄꤅꤆꤇꤈꤉꧐꧑꧒꧓꧔꧕꧖꧗꧘꧙꧰꧱꧲꧳꧴꧵꧶꧷꧸꧹꩐꩑꩒꩓꩔꩕꩖꩗꩘꩙꯰꯱꯲꯳꯴꯵꯶꯷꯸꯹０１２３４５６７８９` (all decimal digits in one script or another).

If you only want to match the ASCII decimal digits `0123456789`, you can add the the `a` flag to the `s`ubstitution or replace `\d` with `[0-9]` (neither should otherwise affect *blank* or *dash punctuation* matching) or you can specify the list of characters explicitly (`[0123456789]` for digits or `[\t\N{SPACE}\N{NO-BREAK SPACE}]` for blanks or `[\N{HYPHEN-MINUS}\N{EN DASH}\N{EM DASH}]` for dashes for instance).

If you're unsure what a character is, you can do `printf %s '–' | uconv -x name` for instance to find out its Unicode name, or use `perl` directly (which would avoid problems linked with different versions of Unicode used by `perl` and `uconv` (icu)):

```
perl -Mcharnames=full -Mopen=locale -lpe '
    s/[^ -~]/"\\N{" . charnames::viacode(ord($&)) . "}"/ge' < your-file
```

Which on your `[34–36]` gives: `[34\N{EN DASH}36]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```bsh
# it also removes the extra spaces
$ sed -e 's/\[[0-9–]*\]//g;s/[[:blank:]]\+/ /g;s/[[:blank:]]\([\.?!:;,]\+\)/\1/g' file
```

Output:

> Local delivery of a wide selection of growth factors (e.g.
> platelet-derived growth factor and bone morphogenetic proteins, for
> example) from electrospun membranes/scaffolds has demonstrated to
> enhance cell activity in vitro as well as bone regeneration in vivo.
> Due to space limitations, the authors recommend that readers refer to
> the outstanding reviews recently published on this topic for further
> details

Comment: `in vitroas` - that should be `in vitro as`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Ups, I'll see to that.

Comment: `in vivo .` - well I'm not OP but I'd prefer it to be `in vivo.`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I was just addressing that, edited the answer adding punctuations.

Comment: It's great now but you forgot to modify `Output:`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Modified the output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match `[` then one or more digits, then `]`.

- The `[` and `]` are considered special characters in regular expressions so you have to escape them with a leading backslash
- A digit can be represented either as `[0-9]` or as `[[:digit:]]`
- You need multiple digits so use `+` to indicate *one or more*

So

```
sed -E 's/\[[[:digit:]]+\]//g'
```

To match a number range, such as `[34–36]` in your example, you need to extend the pattern a little, `[` digits `–` digits `]`. (Note that the dash appears not to be a standard hyphen but the slightly longer *[en dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html)*, or possibly even *[em dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html)*.)

```
sed -E 's/\[[[:digit:]]+–[[:digit:]]+\]//g'
```

To match both of these at the same time you need to make the dash and second number optional by placing it in brackets `(` ... `)` and declaring it so with `?`

```
sed -E 's/\[[[:digit:]]+(–[[:digit:]]+)?\]//g'
```

I've used `sed -E` throughout to indicate Extended regular expressions (ERE), which means more characters are implicitly special and don't need marking out with a backslash.

Comment: Be aware that it's not `-` but `–`, not sure what the name is.

Comment: "em dash" I think

Comment: Instead of those `\+`, `\?` GNUisms, you may want to use `sed -E` and the actual ERE operators (`+`, `?`). That would make it more portable as well as more readable.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I can never remember which need escaping and which don't. I do prefer PCRE for that simple reason alone. Thanks

Comment: The problem with this is that it leaves the spaces: `in vivo  .`.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity it does indeed. I was trying to work out how to match either a leading space or a trailing space without knocking out both (and a blind substitution of optional space + citation reference + space into a single space doesn't work for all cases, either). In the end I left it